# Adding scroll functionality to UITableView's each section

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm going through the example TVAnimationGestures from WWDC 2010. If i have to add a scroll bar / support scrolling functionality for each section of UITableView how can this be achieved?

e.g., assuming the contents shown in each row of a section is wide enough, hence scroll all the rows in each section of 'QuoteCell'.

Thanks.

Comment: lets see if I get you, you need to add scrolling inside each cell of the table, besides the table own scroll?

Comment: Yes, but scrolling should be added to each section of UITableViewcell and not to each cell.

Comment: From an UX point of view, having multiple level of scrolling (one for the table, one for each cell) should be avoided...

Comment: first of all I agree with @StephaneDelcroix, I think the *best/easiest* option is to create more than one table view, one for each "section"

Comment: tkanzakic could you please share some pointers or example for the method. I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a custom UITableViewCell and add a UIScrollView... That's all! :-)

Comment: in this way the scroll can be done for each cell of UITableView, but i need to scroll each section say for e.g., 1st section has 2 rows then simultaneously scroll horizontally 2 rows of 1st section at a time.

Comment: All right, then you probably would have to set a scheme like this: UITableViewController with only ONE UITableViewCell per section and that UITableViewCell would have either another UITableView or UICollection (horizontal scroll would be easier).